# How to make a link redirect to a location with nginx

Tags: nginx

I am having a problem with trying to serve two different sites using the same server.

I have a landing page at the root of [timothylim.is](http://timothylim.is) and a separate blog at [timothylim.is/writing](http://timothylim.is/writing).

I have the following nginx configuration with two different locations:

```
    location / {
            rewrite ^/pserver(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass https://timothyylim.github.io/landing-page/;
    }

    location /writing {
            rewrite ^/pserver(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass https://timothyylim.github.io/writing-online/;
    }
```

However, when any of the links are clicked on the '/writing' location the browser navigates to [timothylim.is/poetry/your-pillar/](http://timothylim.is/poetry) instead of [timothylim.is/writing/poetry/your-pillar/](http://timothylim.is/writing/poetry/your-pillar/).

Is there a way to redirect to a subfolder on the main domain?

Comment: location /writing/ ( may be add forward slash after writing)

Comment: @JigneshJoisar that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the base meta tag instead of trying to change server behaviour.

```
<base href="timothylim.is/writing/">
```